# PresentViewController not working on actionsheet button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiactionsheet

In my code I want to open one view controller as presentviewcontroller using actionsheet. but when i click on the button of actionsheet view is not coming but it's code is executing.

Here is the code invoking the action sheet:

```
// Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Print Full Report",@"Print Only Selected Questions", nil];

//Creating Attributed String with System Font size of 30.0f
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Print Options" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f] , NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor grayColor]}];

//Accessing the Alert View Controller property from Action Sheet
UIAlertController *alertController = [actionSheet valueForKey:@"_alertController"];

//Setting Attributed Title property of Alert View Controller
[alertController setValue:attrString forKey:@"_attributedTitle"];

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
actionSheet.tag = 100;
```

And here are the delegate and associated methods:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)popup clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // tag 1 = save options.  2 = clear options
    switch (buttonIndex) {

        case 0:
            [popup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
            pdfFlag=1;
            [self printReportAction];
            break;
        case 1:
            [popup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
            pdfFlag=2;
            [self printReportAction];
            break;

    }
}

-(void)printReportAction{
    [self presentViewController:previewer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Code formatted for standards and legibility.

Answer (score 0):

did you initialized controller to present?

if so, checked VC for present not nil 
remove these calls:

```
[popup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

There could be several reasons why the code isn't working.  However, ActionSheets were deprecated in iOS 8.3.  I would suggest using UIAlertController instead.  Using an UIAlertController allows you to use blocks which makes tracking how issues much easier and cleaner.

I have mocked up a sample project that recreates what you are trying to accomplish. https://github.com/andyast/ActionSheetTest

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question and should be posted as a comment.